# Google Maps new Renderer in Version 3.32 breaking existing code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have been using the following code to display an image

https://jsfiddle.net/mvbdkmgh/3/

If we use version 3.31 of the apis the rendering works correctly as it has in the past and the image is centered and fully displayed. If one instead changes the url version from 3.31 to 3.32 the map no longer renders correctly ( we get wrapping of the image on the x-axis and the centering doesn't function).

src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=3.32">

```
 getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
        if (!normalizedCoord) {
          return null;
        }
```

Believe this has to do with the getTitleURL function returning a different Coordinate system then the prior version. When I examine the values it does appear that google is now passing a different coordinate system compared to prior values. Does anyone know how to overcome this issue and get the maps to render correctly as per version 3.31 but with the new renderer engine. Cannot find any documentation regarding these changes besides the following page which only indicate that the new render is live in v3.32 and will only be available until august of this year. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer

[Issue in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80507913)

Comment: The v3.32 seems to be returning a wider range of coordinates.   I see values of  (5, 2) being passed to the getNormalizedCoord which returns null.. in version 3.32  no values greater than 4 exist.. Something changed..

Comment: Have you reported your issues on the issue tracker as described on [that page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer)?

Comment: I think so.. here is the link.. Thanks Geocodezip!  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80507913

Comment: It looks like this bug was reported in issue tracker back in February 2018: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73717418. Unfortunately, Google didn't say if this change in new renderer is intentional or it will be fixed.